# Rendering nodes and other content compatible with all themes

Tags: nodes, theming

With a group of several people we're creating a system for students.

Now, on that system we're going to have all kinds of modules that have output, e.g., content types with information about events, a page with a hierarchy of people and groups.

What is the Drupal way of rendering this output?

I know that rendering should be done by the themes. But the problem is that our users should be able to pick a theme they want. Creating separate output for each of those themes is just unfeasibly hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that rendering should be done by the themes.

That is not exactly correct. Theme functions are generally defined from modules, and themes can override them, or implement a theme function that is specific for a purpose.

- [theme_node_preview()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/theme_node_preview/7) is implemented by the Node module
- [theme_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) is implemented by the Field module
- [theme_rdf_metadata()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!rdf!rdf.module/function/theme_rdf_metadata/7) is implemented by the RDF module
- Other theme implementations are contained in the [theme.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/7) file

If you are creating the output for a page, the code for generating it should be in a module. That is because it's a module that can implement [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), which is the hook that defines the menu callback used for pages.
That is what is done from Drupal core code with [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7), which is the page callback for node/%node, and node/%node/view. The page callback is defined from the Node module, not from a theme; themes can eventually alter the output of `node_view()` through the node.tpl.php template file used from `node_view()` to render the node page.

As for outputting the result, there are two methods:

- Returning a string containing the HTML output
- Returning an array with a specific structure (it is called render array) that can be used from [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7)

As example of a page callback that returns a string, see [aggregator_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!aggregator!aggregator.admin.inc/function/aggregator_view/7); as example of page callback that returns a render array, see [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of EDUs use drupal (including mine). For instance Harvard created [Open Scholar](http://scholar.harvard.edu/) to power alot of its sites.

**The best way to render content in D7 is render arrays from your modules.**

Pick a sub-set of drupal modules to support. Create a base theme that implements decent CSS selectors and coloring across all these modules (and their output), allow users to create sub themes -- or colorize your base theme.

Thats about as flexible as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend using Skinr. It allows you to preset classes for certain objects/entities. For example, there's a block being placed on a page, and you make a class for blue, red, and green. The user can then say, "Let this be green!" and there you have it.

It might be something worth looking into.